# Google Analytics reporting api via curl

Tags: php, curl, google-oauth, google-analytics-api

I'm getting the token via oauth consent, but the code below returns 401 error. Should the access token go in the header as 'Authorization'?

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://analyticsreporting.googleapis.com/v4/reports:batchGet");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Authorization: ya29.A0ARrdaM-otJeAg4muGQIIi...............'
));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode(ARRAY_DATA));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Response:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
    "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
        "reason": "CREDENTIALS_MISSING",
        "domain": "googleapis.com",
        "metadata": {
          "method": "google.analytics.reporting.v4.Reporting.GetReports",
          "service": "analyticsreporting.googleapis.com"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should send the access token to the [Google analytics reporting api](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/authorization) as a Authorization header bearer token.

Yes but you are missing the fact that its Bearer token

```
'Authorization: Bearer ya29.A0ARrdaM-otJeAg4muGQIIi...............'
```

Comment: It worked, thanks. A question, does the cURL used get data from new accounts (GA4) or just UA accounts?

Comment: You are using the Google analytics reporting api end point it will only return data from Universal analytics accounts. You need to use the [Google analytics data api endpoint](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1) if you want data from Ga4 accounts.

Comment: Remember to accept the answer if it helped you it will increase your reputation points.  Welcome to stack.